# Unable to run selenium java scripts on jenkins server

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jenkins

I know this question is asked many times here. I tried many ways but i am getting error on jenkins as shown in the screenshot. I am using selenium 4.18.1 , so i dont have chromedriver added in the script . ( gradle project with cucumber and java selenium)
kindly help how to resolve this issue

[image: This is how i am calling the driver and i am setting the value as true for headless while running through jenkins]

[image: This is the error I am getting when scripts are running via jenkins]

Comment: can someone help on this issue please.. I am really stuck.